# how to avoid using for loop in spark (python)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I'm new to pySpark, hope someone coul'd help me.

I have a dataframe with a bunch of filght searches results:

```
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+
|origin|destination|      from|        to|price|
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+
|   TLV|        NYC|2022-01-01|2022-01-05| 1000|
|   TLV|        ROM|2022-03-01|2022-04-05|  480|
|   TLV|        NYC|2022-01-02|2022-01-04|  990|
|   TLV|        NYC|2022-02-01|2022-03-15| 1200|
|   TLV|        NYC|2022-01-02|2022-01-05| 1100|
|   TLV|        BLR|2022-01-01|2022-01-05| 1480|
|   TLV|        NYC|2022-01-02|2022-01-05| 1010|
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+
```

I want to get all the flights prices from the dataframe, based on origin-destination and dates.

I have a list with some date combinations like so:

```
date_combinations = [("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02"), ("2022-01-01", "2022-01-03"), ("2022-01-01", "2022-01-04"),("2022-01-01", "2022-01-05"), ("2022-01-02", "2022-01-03"), ("2022-01-02", "2022-01-04"),("2022-01-02", "2022-01-05"), ("2022-01-03", "2022-01-04"), ("2022-01-03", "2022-01-05"), ("2022-01-04", "2022-01-05") ]
```

What I'm currently doing is filtering the dataframe inside a for loop for every date combination:

```
for date in date_combinations:
    df_date = df.filter((df['from']==date[0])&(df['to']==date[1]))
    if df_date.count()==0:
        results.append([date, 0])
    else:
        results.append([date, df_date.collect()[0]['price']])
```

Output:

```
[('2022-01-01', '2022-01-02'), 0]
[('2022-01-01', '2022-01-03'), 0]
[('2022-01-01', '2022-01-04'), 0]
[('2022-01-01', '2022-01-05'), 1000]
[('2022-01-02', '2022-01-03'), 0]
[('2022-01-02', '2022-01-04'), 990]
[('2022-01-02', '2022-01-05'), 1100]
[('2022-01-03', '2022-01-04'), 0]
[('2022-01-03', '2022-01-05'), 0]
[('2022-01-04', '2022-01-05'), 0]
```

The output is OK, but **I'm sure there is a much more efficient way of doing it, instead of for loop** (which in large datasets will take forever).

**Thanks!**

Comment: If you have more than 1 match on your filter, you only take the first observance, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, the actual code is a bit more complex, I uploaded this only for demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first convert `date_combinations` to a DataFrame (using parallelize or selecting then dropping duplicates if that comes from a data set.

The idea is to do a left join between your dates and the `data` table (we will call it).

First, we want to clean your `data` table and drop duplicates, because you do not want that (because then the left join will also create duplicates on matching records):

```
val mainTableFiltered = data.select("from", "to", "price").dropDuplicates("from", "to")
```

We then join the dates with this cleaned table on `from` and `to` in a `left` join manner, so we do not lose records:

```
dateCombinations.join(mainTableFiltered, Seq("from", "to"), "left")
```

Then, the created records if not matched will be null, therefore we replace nulls with 0s:

```
.withColumn("price", when(col("price").isNull, 0).otherwise(col("price")))
```

And we finally order by `from` and `to` to get the same results (as in your example):

```
.orderBy("from", "to")
```

Full code:

```
val mainTableFiltered = data.select("from", "to", "price").dropDuplicates("from", "to")
dateCombinations.join(mainTableFiltered, Seq("from", "to"), "left")
  .withColumn("price", when(col("price").isNull, 0).otherwise(col("price")))
  .orderBy("from", "to")
```

Final output:

```
+----------+----------+-----+
|      from|        to|price|
+----------+----------+-----+
|2022-01-01|2022-01-02|    0|
|2022-01-01|2022-01-03|    0|
|2022-01-01|2022-01-04|    0|
|2022-01-01|2022-01-05| 1000|
|2022-01-02|2022-01-03|    0|
|2022-01-02|2022-01-04|  990|
|2022-01-02|2022-01-05| 1100|
|2022-01-03|2022-01-04|    0|
|2022-01-03|2022-01-05|    0|
|2022-01-04|2022-01-05|    0|
+----------+----------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like a great solution for me.

Comment: What if I have two matching results with different prices, for example |2022-01-01|2022-01-05| 1000| and |2022-01-01|2022-01-05| 900| and I want to get the cheaper option?

Comment: If you want to find the cheaper option, then in this line:

val mainTableFiltered = data.select("from", "to", "price").dropDuplicates("from", "to")

instead of select, you can groupBy "from" and "to" and find the maximum "price", the rest of the code stays the same

Answer (score 0):

You can create a df from your list of dates and join both dfs:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
     ('TLV','NYC','2022-01-01','2022-01-05','1000')
    ,('TLV','ROM','2022-03-01','2022-04-05','480')
    ,('TLV','NYC','2022-01-02','2022-01-04','990')
    ,('TLV','NYC','2022-02-01','2022-03-15','1200')
    ,('TLV','NYC','2022-01-02','2022-01-05','1100')
    ,('TLV','BLR','2022-01-01','2022-01-05','1480')
    ,('TLV','NYC','2022-01-02','2022-01-05','1010')
    ],
    ['origin','destination','from','to','price']
)

df.show()

+------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+
|origin|destination|      from|        to|price|
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+
|   TLV|        NYC|2022-01-01|2022-01-05| 1000|
|   TLV|        ROM|2022-03-01|2022-04-05|  480|
|   TLV|        NYC|2022-01-02|2022-01-04|  990|
|   TLV|        NYC|2022-02-01|2022-03-15| 1200|
|   TLV|        NYC|2022-01-02|2022-01-05| 1100|
|   TLV|        BLR|2022-01-01|2022-01-05| 1480|
|   TLV|        NYC|2022-01-02|2022-01-05| 1010|
+------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+

date_combinations = [("2022-01-01", "2022-01-02"), ("2022-01-01", "2022-01-03"), ("2022-01-01", "2022-01-04"),("2022-01-01", "2022-01-05"), ("2022-01-02", "2022-01-03"), ("2022-01-02", "2022-01-04"),("2022-01-02", "2022-01-05"), ("2022-01-03", "2022-01-04"), ("2022-01-03", "2022-01-05"), ("2022-01-04", "2022-01-05") ]

df_date_combinations = spark.createDataFrame(date_combinations, ['from','to'])

df\
    .join(df_date_combinations, ['from','to'])\
    .show()

+----------+----------+------+-----------+-----+
|      from|        to|origin|destination|price|
+----------+----------+------+-----------+-----+
|2022-01-01|2022-01-05|   TLV|        NYC| 1000|
|2022-01-01|2022-01-05|   TLV|        BLR| 1480|
|2022-01-02|2022-01-04|   TLV|        NYC|  990|
|2022-01-02|2022-01-05|   TLV|        NYC| 1100|
|2022-01-02|2022-01-05|   TLV|        NYC| 1010|
+----------+----------+------+-----------+-----+
```